# Error while 'npm start'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Material Design Lite with Angular 2. It does not let start the server

```
document.querySelector('#notifier').MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what are you trying to do , this doesn't seem ok an Angular way at all .

But to get around that error , one quick way is to cast it to `<any>`

```
   (<any>document.querySelector('#notifier')).MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
```